# JPA data dictionary structure

Tags: jpa, data-dictionary

I define two table data structure in 3 tables , Table Groups and Table Persons

[image]

for example table person :
1) define table name in Tables
2) field of person define in table Fields .
3) data inserted in table Data .

so , john is a row (first_name field) of table Persons .

How can implement this data structure like Oracle data dictionary in database with JPA ?

actually , I develop a modular system and this is stupid idea to create table per module (If module need a table) .

more explain :
I won't create table at runtime . my own project used OSGI for dynamic module . some times that module need a own table . so I won't modules change my ERD with dangerous relations .

Comment: Can you post your approach on implementing this? People here can help with improving it.

Comment: nobody can help me ? I want to understand how can create custom data dictionary in Oracle Database .